# Is it possible to use SQL Server in python without external libs?

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm developing on an environment which I'm not allowed to install anything. It's a monitoring server and I'm making a script to work with logs and etc.

So, I need to connect to a SQL Server with Python 2.7 without any lib like pyodbc installed. Is it possible to make this? I've found nothing I could use to connect to that database.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Newp! But, you could use a linked server in install what ever you want.

Comment: @scsimon I've considered this but the load of data I will transfer is kinda high per sec and I wouldn't want to risk taking some timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain things you can do to run sql from the command line from python:

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output('sqlcmd  -Q "SELECT * FROM db.table"')
print x
```

Comment: Looks like this will be the best way to do. Thanks